# How to plot sphere or dots at 3D points in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I like to plot small spheres or dots with certain small radius at arrays of 3D points. I used Sphere GameObject in Prefabs and Instantiate it whenever I need to plot. Since I plot a lot, system can't handle.

The way I need to plot is

```
for (int i = 1; i < 200; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
       Instantiate(dot, start[j], new Quaternion(0,0,0,0));
       GameObject.Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("dot"), 0.01f);
    }
}
```

Since it is changing from 1 to 200. So the system can't handle it even I destroy them.

So I change to

```
for (int i = 1; i < 200; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        //Here devicePlots.Count is same as i
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.vertices = devicePlots.ToArray();
        Color[] colors = new Color[devicePlots.Count];
        int[] indices = new int[devicePlots.Count];
        for (int j = 0; j < devicePlots.Count; j++)
        {
            indices[j] = j;
            colors[j] = Color.red;
        }
    }
}
```

But nothing come out.

My queries are 
(1)If the first approach using Instantiating GameObject is right approach, how to make so that the system can handle.
(2)If the second approach is appropriate, why I don't see dots?
I am new to Unity. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the system can't handle it? What happens?

Comment: The program becomes very slow, mouse can't be moved etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets look at the first approach
The main problem here, and the reason why the system cant handle the calculations (I assume it takes too long and unity freezes), is because you use Instantiate/Destroy (FindWithTag too, you'd better just save the reference in Start, and read from it directly) in a big number of iterations.

To optimize this, you can create all the gameobjects (instantiate them) beforehand (editorMode or in start) than change their positions. This should give you instantenious results if you just change their positions, and stop using Instantiate/Destroy EVERY time in the frame, they are your main problem in the first approach.

As for the second one, this code is creating a mesh, defining its vertices, but they are essnetially just points, if you want them to be shown you have to define trianlges and normals for them. Read more about meshes if you want to use this approach, but I dont think this will give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks Arman. I made array of dots and SetActive(false); Then i made SetActive(true); one by one.